# Most appropriate HTTP status code for "job in progress"

Tags: http, rest, response, httpresponse, http-status-codes

What is the most appropriate HTTP status code to give to a client to mean "your request is fine, but it is still in progress;  check back shortly in the exact same place."

For example, say the client submits an initial request to start a heavy query, and the server immediately returns a URL that the client can poll periodically for the result.  In the case the client calls this URL before the job is completed, what is the most appropriate HTTP status code to return?

**202 Accepted** would be my first impulse.  Is this the best one, or is there a better one that is more idiomatic for this purpose in REST interfaces?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To me, *202 Accepted* would be the best way to go.

See the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) on the W3C website.

> 10.2.3 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
>   upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
>   There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
>   operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to
>   allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
>   batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
>   requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
>   the process is completed. The entity returned with this response
>   SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and
>   either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user
>   can expect the request to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a similar problem. I have an API that looks like this:

```
POST /jobs               # Creates a job
GET /jobs/{jobId}        # Gets a job
GET /jobs/{jobId}/output # Gets job output
```

My API flow looks like this:

```
POST /jobs               -> 202 Accepted, Link header to created object
GET /jobs/{jobId}        -> 200 OK, includes status field
GET /jobs/{jobId}/output -> 200 OK if job completed successfully, XXX otherwise?
```

So `POST /jobs` returns `202` when creating the job, users poll `GET /jobs/{jobId}` to check status, and use `/jobs/{jobId}/output` to get the results. Here is where I'm landing:

- If the job completed with success, then `200 OK`, as shown above
- If the job completed with failure, then `409 Conflict`
- If the job is processing, then either `204 No Content` or `425 Too Early`, depending on if I decide not polling `GET /jobs/{jobId}` and waiting is valid user behavior or a client error, respectively. I know `425` is technically a protocol-level error, but it's looks like the closest thing to me.

I like [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) as a design concept, but it feels like we're missing either some important HTTP codes, guidance, or both before it's fully useable.