# Appropriate response for job result in REST API

Tags: rest, http

I manage a `REST API` that has an interface to `POST` code from users. This code gets compiled and should send a result to the user but, since compiling can take a long time I prefer to send back to the user a **202 Accepted** HTTP code.

On the event the user tries to `GET` the resource again, what would be appropriate codes both for success, meaning the compilation has been successful, and error, meaning it was not?

Comment: Returning `202 Accepted` seems like a good choice when the resource is not ready yet. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824969/most-appropriate-http-status-code-for-job-in-progress). Status codes for accessing the resource again? That depends on the semantics of "success" and "error" here. Are we talking about POSTing code to somewhere and then doing a GET later to get the result?

Comment: Exactly, I edited the question again to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `GET` on that resource after it the compilation is finished, I'd return `200 OK` along with a response body indicating the success or failure of the compilation. Here I'll use JSON as the media type. For instance, when compilation was successful you would have this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
    "status" : "success"
}
```

and if the compilation failed you would perhaps include the reason why it failed, maybe taken from the compiler output or similar:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
    "status" : "failure",
    "reason" : "syntax error"
}
```

Comment: Using this line of reasoning, if the job is still processing the result would be a `"status" : "working"` or similar I guess.

Comment: @PedroMontotoGarcía You wouldn't really need a response body in that case since the status code `202 Accepted` already indicates that the resource is being worked on. You still need a body to differentiate the two `200 OK` responses though.